# What does it mean when the EOM of a field is trivially satisfied if other EOMs are satisfied?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

If a Lagrangian has the fields $a$, $b$ and $c$ whose equations of motion (EOM) are denoted by $E_a=0, E_b=0$ and $E_c=0$ respectively, then if
\begin{align}
E_a=f_1(a,b,c)\,E_b+f_2(a,b,c)\,E_c\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are some functions of the fields, if $E_b$ and $E_c$ are satisfied, then $E_a$ is automatically satisfied.

Does this tell us anything particular about the nature of field $a$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Let us consider the reduced action
   $$ S_{\rm red}[a]~:=~S[a,b\!=\!b_{\rm cl}(a),c\!=\!c_{\rm cl}(a)]$$
   where we have inserted solutions for the $b$ and $c$ fields.
2. If we assume that the EOMs $E_b\approx 0\approx E_c$ are algebraic (rather than differential) equations, then $S_{\rm red}[a]$ is a local action.
3. In such cases OP's identity (1) implies that $S_{\rm red}[a]$ is a boundary term (modulo possible topological obstruction), i.e. $S_{\rm red}[a]$ does not depend on the $a$ field in the bulk. In other words, $a$ is a gauge field of the reduced theory, with the most general gauge transformation $a\to a + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon=\epsilon(x)$ is an arbitrary function that vanishes on the boundary.