# If the solution of a field vanishes on-shell does it mean anything particular?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

Let us consider an action $S=S(a,b,c)$ which is a functional of the fields $a,\, b,\,$ and $c$. The solution of the field $c$ is given by the expression $f(a,b)$. On taking into account the relations obtained from the solutions for $a$ and $b$, we find that $f(a,b)=0$. If the solution for the field $c$ vanishes on-shell, does it mean anything particular?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768539/2451

Comment: In that related post, the question was about the EOM of a field, say $c$, being trivially satisfied but not necessarily the solution of that field vanishing. In this question I am asking what happens if the solution for the field vanishes, which can be different from the EOM being trivially satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this means that the $c$-solution $f(a,b)$ belongs to the [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) of the EOMs for $a$ and $b$ (and their consequences), i.e. it is a linear combination thereof.